# wait() и notify() в java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Такое дело. Есть список с пассажирами, которые ждут, пока каждого разбудит поток. Но когда он ходит по ним в итерации, просыпается только один. Почему?

На картинке ниже в логах видно, что пассажиры с **айди 19 и 12 выходят на одном этаже** - но сообщает об этом только один пассажир

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это выглядит в коде:

```
//смотрим, какие пассажиры доехали
            passengerArrived = passengers.stream()
                    .filter(p -> p.getDestination() == currentFloor)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//удаляем тех пассажиров, которых мы доставили
            passengers.removeAll(passengerArrived);
//"будим" пассажиров, чтобы те вышли
            for (Passenger pass : passengerArrived) {
                synchronized (pass) {
                    pass.notify();
                }
            }
//------------------------
class Passenger {
///some code
@SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {
            log.info("Passenger {} waiting an elevator...", id);
            wait();
            log.info("Passenger {} entered elevator!", id);
            wait();
            log.info("Passenger {} arrived his floor - {}! Good!", id, destination);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: То есть вы запутались, имея всю программу при себе, но предлагаете вам помочь по тому обрывку, что вы привели? Он даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: Вы уверены, что поток исполняющий `run` пассажира 12 действительно ждет? `wait` может проснуться и без `notify`.

Comment: Попробуйте поймать (`catch`) `InteruptedException` и вы поймете, что метод `run()` одного из ожидающих потоков, свалится по этому исключению (во втором `wait()`), не успев напечатать то, что он хотел.

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець - почему свалится? Он внутри `synchronized` блока.

Comment: @Anastasiya  а почему ты уведомляешь доехавших пассажиров, а не оставшихся?

Comment: Ну мне ж надо выгнать доехавших, а не оставшихся) ато они, получается, и не доедут

Comment: А остальные когда извещаются?

Comment: когда currentFloor конкретного лифта равен destination пассажира

Comment: тебе стоит весь код привести